# Reroute backend link with one port to a frontend route with another port

Tags: vue.js, flask, routes, single-page-application

I have a flask app that sends a link to users with localhost:5000. My front end SPA is running on port 6000, so when a user clicks that link, it doesn't lead anywhere since the SPA doesn't know what to do with the 5000 port. How can I make it so that clicking on that link leads to something like localhost:6000/hello? Keep in mind, I can't change how the link from the flask app is generated. Do I use a reverse proxy? Are there any other methods?

Comment: users aren't going to end up anywhere with links to "localhost".  how are the links going to work in production?